# Flutter / Google Firestore StreamBuilder not upToDate with Database

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with my StreamBuilder.
In this case I have a TabBarView with 3 StreamBuilders (code down this post with one of the three tabs). When something is deleted from the db, the builder shows wrong data. Sometimes the item is still there, sometimes it doubles. I tried to delete the two orderBy statements from the query. I hot reloaded and the data was right. After adding the statements again and hot reloaded, everything was fine.

Why is this happening? Is it because of the orderBy statements?

Thanks!

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance
              .collection("bookings")
              .document(localUser.centerName)
              .collection("center_bookings")
              .where("customerId", isEqualTo: localUser.userId)
              .orderBy("bookedMonth", descending: false)
              .orderBy("bookedDay", descending: false)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}");
            }
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                );
              default:
                return Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 10.0),
                  child: ListView(
                      children: snapshot.data.documents.map((document) {
                    if (_datesNext7Days.contains(document["bookedFor"])) {
                      return Padding(...);
                    } else {
                      return SizedBox();
                    }
                  }).toList()),
                );
            }
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

try to return yeild yourdata type for continues stream of data in streambuilder 
here is the example and don't forget the * in async

```
 static Stream<List<MeetingItem>> getMeetingsList() async* {
   Firestore fireStore = Firestore.instance;
   try {
    var collectionsMeeting = fireStore.collection(VConstants.KEYS.meetings);

    var snapshots = collectionsMeeting.snapshots();

   await for (QuerySnapshot snap in snapshots) {
    List<MeetingItem> meetingList = [];
    snap.documents.forEach((element) {
      meetingList.add(MeetingItem(element.documentID, element.data));
    });
    yield meetingList;
  }
 } catch (e) {
  print(e);
 }
}
}
```

call this method from this line

```
 StreamBuilder(
      stream: getMeetingsList()//customize it with your return value
```